# How to interact between 2 config files

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a **config.prop** file which is being called from **ngConfig.js** file which is a service file. This prop file contains an URL which I need in my 2nd service file **ngContent.js** .

These files are being called individually from **resolve**.

```
$routeProvider.
when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
    controller: LoginController,
    resolve: {
        urlData: function(Config) {
            return Config.prop().then(function(response) {
                return response;
            });
        },
        contentData:function(Content){
            return Content.prop().then(function(response){
                return response;
            });
        }
    }
})
```

The response I am getting from **urlData**, which is resolving my response from **ngConfig.js** is the content of the **config.prop**. I need this response in my **ngContent.js** file.

The content of **ngConfig.js** is

```
angular.module('ngConfig', [])
.service('Config', function ($http, $rootScope, $document) {

    //API calling method for all method
    this.prop = function () {
        try {
            //API calling
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "application/json",
                data: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: 'config.prop',
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            }, function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            return ex;
        }
        return promise;
    };

});
```

The content of **ngContent.js** is

```
angular.module('ngContent', [])
.service('Content', function ($http, $rootScope, $document) {

    //API calling method for all method
    this.prop = function () {
        try {
            //API calling
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: "application/json",
                data: 'json',
                cache: false,
                url: API_URL
            }).then(function (response) {
                return response;
            }, function (response) {
                return response;
            });
        } catch (ex) {
            return ex;
        }
        return promise;
    };

});
```

The *API_URL* is present in **config.prop** file, which is called from **ngConfig.js** file.

I hope I was able to present my problem clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may pass **urlData** to contentData, like this, and then pass it to *Content.prop()*.

```
contentData:  function(Content, urlData){
    return Content.prop(urlData).then(function(response){
        return response;
       });
    }
```

**Edit**

> This doesn't work with **$routeProvider**, you have to use **$stateProvider** of ui-router.
>   I have used it and it works. Use it the same way as discussed above.

Comment: it is not working. I am not able to get the **urlData** value in **ngContent** service file. Is there any other alternative other than the **$stateProvider**?

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and was not working with $routeProvider, but was working with $stateProvider.

You can combine both resolves to one i.e wait for Config.prop() to resolve and then call Content.prop().